# How do I parse XML from a WCF response

Tags: c#, xml, wcf, rest, get

I receive the following response when calling a GET to a WCF service using WebClient DownloadString:

```
    <?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><string>false</string>
```

How do I get only `false` from that?

Comment: What do u mean by u "How do I stay only with "false"in C#?"

Comment: It's XML. Look up "LINQ to XML"